# Jmockit MissingInvocation in mocking findComponentInParents

Tags: jmockit

```
public abstract class AbstractValidator implements Validator
{
    @Override
    public abstract void validate(
        FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
        throws ValidatorException;

  protected String buildValidationMessage(String param)
    {
        return param;
    }

}



public abstract class AbstractMatchValidator extends AbstractValidator {

    protected String field1ComponentId;
    protected String field1InputLabel;
    protected String inputLabel;

    protected abstract String cleanBeforeComparing(String value);

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, 
                         UIComponent component, 
                         Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        UIInput input1 = Components.findComponentInParents(component,
                field1ComponentId);
        if (null == input1) {
            return;
        }
        String field1 = null;
        if (input1.isValid()) {
            field1 = this.cleanBeforeComparing((String)input1.getValue());
        }
        String confirmField = this.cleanBeforeComparing((String) value);


        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(field1) && !field1.equals(confirmField)) {
            input1.setValid(false);
            FacesMessage msg = buildValidationMessage(context, 
                    this.inputLabel,
                    this.fieldToMatchInputLabel);
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }
    }



public class EmployeeIDMatchValidator extends AbstractFieldMatchValidator {

    protected String cleanBeforeComparing(String value) {
        return value.replace("_",":");
    }



public class SSNMatchValidator extends AbstractFieldMatchValidator {

    protected String cleanBeforeComparing(String value) {
        return value.replace("_","-");
    }
```

And I have this Jmockit test:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class EmployeeIDMatchValidatorTest {

@Tested
EmployeeIDMatchValidator validator;

    @Test
    @SuppressWarnings(value = "unchecked")
    public final void testNoExceptionIsThrownForNoEmployeeIDValue(
            @Mocked FacesContext facesContext,
            @Mocked UIInput textInput,
            @Mocked UIInput uiInput){
        new MockUp<Components>() {
            @Mock
            public  <C extends UIComponent> C findComponentInParents(UIComponent component, String clientId) {
                return (C) textInput;
            }
        };

        new Expectations() {{
            textInput.getSubmittedValue();
                result="9-9192121-1";

            MessageFormat.format(anyString, any);
            result = "Employee ID is invalid.";

            }};

        validator.validate(facesContext, uiInput, "9-91921211");
    }


}
```

When I ran this test, the textInput and uiInput values shows as null. Can someone please tell me why the values are not passed to findComponentInParents method.

I am getting this error in the logs:

```
mockit.internal.MissingInvocation: Missing 1 invocation to:
javax.faces.component.UIInput#getSubmittedValue()
   on mock instance: javax.faces.component.UIInput@1a04f701
```

what is that I am missing here in this test? please help.

Answer (score 0):

JMockit is letting you know that you're not invoking that method, and according to the code you shared, you're "expecting" one invocation by using the block:

```
 new Expectations() {{
            textInput.getSubmittedValue();
                result="9-9192121-1"; ... 
  }};
```

If what you want to return an specific value that ok, but the method that you're testing doesn't call the ***getSubmittedValue()***, but it call the ***getValue()*** method.

```
new Expectations() {{
                uiInput.getValue();
                    result="9-9192121-1"; 
  //... more code
}};
```

You might want to add to your expectations the ***isValid()*** method too, for the ***getValue()*** to be called.

```
new Expectations() {{
            uiInput.isValid(); result = true;
            uiInput.getValue(); result="9-9192121-1";

           // ... more code
    }};
```

Don't forget everything you mentioned inside the static block of Expectations should be called at least once. For more information:
http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Expectations.html